# How can I use mutable dict for Werkzeug's Request data?

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I would like to use mutable dict for `request.args` and `request.form`. Werkzeug and Flask create an `ImmutableMultiDict` for this data. Is there a way to make this mutable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Werkzeug documentation, you update the [`parameter_storage_class`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.Request.parameter_storage_class) attribute on the `Request` class to use the type you want. If you also want to do the same thing for data other than `args` and `form`, you update the [`dict_storage_class`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.Request.dict_storage_class) attribute. The documentation notes:

> It is ... possible to use mutable structures, but this is not recommended.

It is not recommended to make this mutable because the request data is whatever came from the client. Changing it will mean it no longer matches what the client sent. There is likely a better way to pass around custom values, such as using Flask's `before_request` and `g`.

The [Flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/patterns/subclassing/) shows how to modify and use a `Request` subclass for an application.

> ````py
> from flask import Flask, Request
> from werkzeug.datastructures import ImmutableOrderedMultiDict
>
> class MyRequest(Request):
>     parameter_storage_class = ImmutableOrderedMultiDict
>
> class MyFlask(Flask):
>     request_class = MyRequest ```
> ````